# is there a function to change current date to an assumption date in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sql-date-functions

I have a list of data with dates dated as 2021-01-01 to 2021-12-31.
Hence i do need to make an assumption that my current date as 2021-01-01 instead of current date (2022-07-18)
Is there a way that i can set this in my SQL code ?

Comment: it feels like an xy problem. what are you trying to do anyway? filter rows based on dates?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not that function or that possibility. If you need it, you need to rewrite your code to allow parameters (for regress or unit tests). Usually using `CURRENT_DATE` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in code directly is partially bad design, because it disallow to write tests. Good code should be testable. You can use function's default arguments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(d date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE)
RETURNS date AS $$
BEGIN
  ...
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- run with specified parameter
SELECT foo('20220717');

-- run with current date
SELECT foo();
```